# how to do web server programming in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to know how to do web server programming in ruby. in short please explain what does ruby provide to replace Servlets, JSP's

Comment: Rails is the big gun in web programming for Ruby. If you don't know Ruby then I wouldn't recommend starting with Rails as that would be a very steep learning curve and a lot of parts wouldn't make any sense. [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) is a lightweight web environment for Ruby that is quite powerful. Between the two is [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/). I'd recommend starting with Sinatra to get your feet wet with Ruby and the Ruby way, then look at the other two and see what feels good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested, Rails is the most popular framework, although there are others out there that are gaining popularity.

If you've been using Java, then you're used to declaring servlets including the dispatcher servlet and then defining custom routes to your controller actions. In Rails, routes are convention driven. So for example, if you have a `User` object, then putting `resources :users` in your `config/routes.rb` will create routes to a handful of REST actions. [See this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for examples of this. You can also make custom routes for more specialized cases, but your typical mappings will be enough for most use cases.

You are also used to JSPs. ERB is very similar to JSP but a little easier to work with. You can put server code in between `<% %>` markup, and you can put in HTML markup and JavaScript tags (although your JavaScript should really be in JavaScript files, but that's a different discussion), and also Rails helpers that generate html (JSP has similar utilities). You can also define custom form builders so you can make your own helpers, which is pretty handy in some use cases. However, ERB is losing popularity and a lot of people prefer haml, which completely abstracts away html markup. But I have never had any objection to ERB.

Other than that, Rails uses the MVC pattern which you may be familiar with if you've used Spring-MVC, but in Rails it's convention over configuration, so when you have an action called `index` in your controller, Rails assumes you have an index.html.erb in the corresponding views path. So you don't usually specify your views, although Rails makes it very convenient to respond to different content-type requests. Example:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render :json => @obj }
end
```

So the default response would look for an html.erb template but if it's an AJAX request it would send back a JSON object. You can also return xml and whatever else you want, although some content types might require plugins/gems.

If you're used to Spring-MVC I think you'll find Rails familiar on one hand but also extremely convenient on the other. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the official [Guides to Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

Answer (score 1):

i think than what you need is a web framework,  in this case(Ruby) Ruby on Rails or Sinatra for example.

Answer (score 1):

I love these labs.  They do a great job explaining the architecture of Rails and it has Zombies in it.

http://railsforzombies.org/labs

Answer (score 1):

You can read some tutorials of Rails, understand the mvc pattern of it, and compare the parts to J2EE.

There are similar ideas, but in my opinion, rails is more convenient that you don't need to write so many xml configuration. And by using ruby language, you can have a much higher efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the http://railstutorial.com. You can read the html tutorial on line and code at the same time. By the time you finish, you will have learned so much.